# python parse csv to lists

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file thru which I want to parse the data to the lists.
So I am using the python csv module to read that
so basically the following:

```
import csv
fin = csv.reader(open(path,'rb'),delimiter=' ',quotechar='|')
print fin[0]
#gives the following
['"1239","2249.00","1","3","2011-02-20"']

#lets say i do the following
ele = str(fin[0])
ele = ele.strip().split(',')    
print ele
#gives me following  
['[\'"1239"', '"2249.00"', '"1"', '"3"', '"2011-02-20"\']']
```

now
    ele[0] gives me --> output---> ['"1239"

How do I get rid of that ['
In the end, I want to do is get 1239 and convert it to integer.. ?
Any clues why this is happening
Thanks

Edit:**Never mind.. resolved thanks to the first comment **

Comment: Why are you setting the delimiter to `' '` when those actually appear to be comma separated values?

Answer (score 1):

Change your delimiter to ',' and you will get a list of those values from the csv reader.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are converting a list to a string, there is no need to do this. Grab the first element of the list (in this case it is a string) and parse that:

```
>>> a = ['"1239","2249.00","1","3","2011-02-20"']
>>> a
['"1239","2249.00","1","3","2011-02-20"']
>>> a[0]
'"1239","2249.00","1","3","2011-02-20"'
>>> b = a[0].replace('"', '').split(',')
>>> b[-1]
'2011-02-20'
```

of course before you do replace and split string methods you should check if the type is string or handle the exception if it isn't.

Also Blahdiblah is correct your delimiter is probably wrong.